# APP_INITIALIZER order in nested modules

Tags: angular, initialization

I have two modules – main module and one that is imported. They both have `APP_INITIALIZER`. Is the order of calling of initializers **guaranteed**? I tested few times and internal is always called first, but is it just a coincidence?

```
// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EnvironmentModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    PermissionsService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (permissionsService: PermissionsService) => {
        return () => permissionsService.fetchUserPermissions()
      },
      deps: [PermissionsService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

// environment.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    EnvironmentService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (environmentService: EnvironmentService) => () => environmentService.getEnvConfig(),
      deps: [EnvironmentService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class EnvironmentModule {}
```